# Functions that maps unit circle into unit circle

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-geometry

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4868/mapping-that-takes-unit-circle-to-unit-circle) and [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3408/characterizing-nonconstant-entire-functions-with-modulus-1-on-the-unit-circle) problems discuses the characterization of Analytic functions which maps unit circle on to itself.

> I would like to know the characterization of functions which map unit circle into itself with finitely many poles inside the open unit disk.
>   Is there any such characterization?

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1240087/meromorphic-functions-on-the-unit-disk.

Comment: How could a function with a pole on the circle map the circle to itself?